# Content-files with NuGet are very very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, package-managers

I have a common ASP.NET web application that is shared by multiple sites. I used NuGet to package this common web application and distribute it over the multiple sites. Following this idea: [Multiple ASP.NET web applications depending on a common base application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816803/#6817690).

By doing this, I end up with some issues. When updating for a new version, NuGet becomes **really slow**. This is because of the 800 content-files it contains.  Somehow NuGet has to take around 1~2 seconds for each content-file it needs to uninstall, ending up with approximately **25 minutes** for uninstall and 5 minutes for install . Especially with a TFS-binding. Looking at the source-code of NuGet I figured that the API of Visual Studio where NuGet is talking to is the bottleneck. Causing **Visual Studio** to peak around **100% of CPU-usage** the whole process.

So I thought, if Visual Studio is that slow, maybe I can do it without it. To my disappointment the NuGet commandline (that runs without Visual Studio) only downloads a package and unzips it. It won't update the project-file due the fact that some Powershell-scripts could reference to the DTE-object... ( although I don't).

Now I'm wondering: what are my options?

1. Doing some XML-magic on the project-file to add content-items? What are the drawbacks of doing this? Is there already a tool for this?
2. Doing some magic with build scripts?
3. Throw away the content-files out of the package and use another tool like Bower or something? How may this be integrated into the project? Because eventually I want to see the content-files I have.
4. Not using NuGet at all but something else ...? OpenWrap? Horn? (seems to no longer be active) Or maybe no package manager at all?

Please help me find the best solution :)

.

One other thing that frustrates me is when performing a NuGet update, it does an uninstall followed by an install. Why, if the changes between versions could be minimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is that instead of adding 800 content files, you can embed them as resources in your shared library.

Then use something like `EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider` https://github.com/mcintyre321/EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider to serve them up.

That way NuGet is simply replacing the .dll instead of 800 individual files.

There are plenty of articles online about how to use `VirtualPathProvider`.

**EDIT**: Questions about performance

The solution seems relatively simple, so I would just try it and see if the performance is acceptable. The nice thing is that you don't have to do anything special with paths in your web app.

Here are the steps you need to do:

1. In your resource library, set the content files to embedded resource. You can do that quickly by opening up the *.csproj* file in a text editor and replacing `<Content` with `<EmbeddedResource`.
2. Add a reference to your resource library to your web app.
3. Add the `EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider` NuGet package to your web app
4. Register the virtual path provider. Here's an example to register using `AppInitialize()` stored in the `App_Code` folder.

```c#
namespace TestWebProject.App_Code
{
    public class RegisterVirtualPathProvider
    {
        public static void AppInitialize()
        {
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider.Vpp()
            {
                {typeof (Marker).Assembly, @"..\TestResourceLibrary"},

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, are there any drawbacks by using this? Like a possible performance lag for the end users?

Comment: Updated answer with some more info

Comment: @sebas2day, there are performance problems, it occupies more memory as entire assembly is in the memory and, loading of application will be slower, IIS will not cache them as static content, IIS will also not compress them as static content compression, you will end up using more cpu in runtime.