# How to validate that content files added by NuGet to a project are untouched

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

We have a NuGet package with a lot of content files.
We would like to force developers to change these files only via NuGet update and not directly.

**Question 1: 
How we would achieve this?**

We have thought about build-time validation for which we need to know checksums of the original files

**Question 2:
Does the build time validation sound like a right approach?**

and possible options to calculate these checksums are:

1. at  install time calculate checksums of the content files and save them somewhere.
   a.  In the project items metadata/attributes
   Cons: seems there is no way to add a new Property to ProjectItems in install.ps1
   b.  In a separate file and add it to Source control
   Cons: require duplication of the NuGet.Core logic
2. calculate these checksums during NuGet package build, store into a file (a kind of catalog file) and add this file to the NuGet package as a content
3. compare content of the files from the project with the content of same files in NuGet repository.  Cons: how to find to which NuGet package belongs some file?

**Question 3:
Is there a conventional way to achieve this at build time validation?**

Comment: What kind of content files are these? If they shouldn't be edited perhaps you should add then as resources instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345438/content-files-with-nuget-are-very-very-slow/23348488#23348488

Comment: These content files contain configuration settings. 
EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider looks interesting. But it only serves for Web apps. Is there something like it for console app?